# Mocking an ElasticSearch client using C# Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, elasticsearch, moq

I'm testing my class `ElasticUtility` which requires an instance of the `ElasticClient` in order to work properly so I mocked such class and injected it into the `ElasticUtility` instance (`utility`)

```
    private ElasticUtility utility;
    private Mock<IElasticClient> elasticClientMock;
    private string elasticSearchIndexName;

    elasticClientMock = new Mock<IElasticClient>();
    utility = new UhhElasticUtility(elasticClientMock.Object);
```

This is the actual test code:

```
[Test]
public void GetGetPvDataClientReturnNull()
{
    // arrange
    var groupId = "groupid";
    var startTime = new DateTime(2015, 08, 17, 13, 30, 00);
    var endTime = new DateTime(2015, 08, 17, 13, 40, 00);
    
    // act
    utility.GetPvData(groupId, startTime, endTime);

    // assert
    elasticClientMock.Verify(ec => ec.Search<SegmentRecord>(It.IsAny<Nest.ISearchRequest>()), Times.Once());
}
```

I get a Null reference exception when the Moq library calls the `.Search()` method inside the mocked `ElastiClient`.

EDIT:

the constructor of `ElasticUtility`:

```
    protected ElasticUtility(IElasticClient elasticClient, string elasticIndexName)
    {
        this.ElasticClient = elasticClient;
        this.ElasticIndexName = elasticIndexName;
    }
```

EDIT: `GetPvData`() method:

```
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetPvData(string groupId, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        var res = ElasticClient.Search<SegmentRecord>(s => s
            .Index(ElasticIndexName)
            .Filter(f =>
                f.Term(t => t.HistoryId, groupId) &&
                f.Range(i =>
                    i.OnField(a => a.DateTime).LowerOrEquals(startTime))).SortAscending(p => p.DateTime).Size(1)).Documents.ToList();

        return res.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: please add the C'tor of `UhhElasticUtility` and the implementation of `GetPvData`

Comment: could it be because it's protected?

Comment: no protected C'tor is not the issue... but i asked about `UhhElasticUtility` C'tor and `GetPvData`...

Comment: and this is the GetPvData() implementation

Comment: the problem is `.Documents` you didn't set an expectation, then search return `null`...

Comment: How can I add an expectation on such .Document?

Comment: See my answer, replace the comments with the correct types and instances

Comment: If you had an answer, make it an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `NullReferenceException` occured because you didn't specify a behavior on `search` method. Your `search` method returns null and then you calls `.Document` on the null.

The way to specify a behavior is as the following:

```
elasticClientMock.Setup(x => x.Search<SegmentRecord>(
                             It.IsAny</* put here the right Func */>))
        .Returns( /* put here the instance you want to return */);
```

you have to replace my comments with the correct types.

Comment: I'm unable to create an instance of Nest.ISearchResponse<SegmentRecord> to pass it to the .Returns() method.

Comment: if I write:     var test = Nest.ISearchResponse<SegmentRecord>(); it says "Interface name is not valid at this point" . oh it's an interface!

Comment: even with Nest.SearchResponse<SegmentRecord> doesn't work

Comment: Use `Moq` to create the instace of `Nest.ISearchResponse<SegmentRecord>();` or create a custom type, if you use `Moq` make sure that you didn't forget to initialize the fake object properties.

Comment: yes but it didn't work. I mocked the response as:           var response = new Mock<Nest.ISearchResponse<SegmentRecord>>();
            elasticClientMock.Setup(ec => ec.Search<SegmentRecord>(It.IsAny<Nest.ISearchRequest>())).Returns(response.Object); but the .Search() function keeps returning null

Answer (score 3):

Code is from .git here: https://gist.github.com/netoisc/5d456850d79f246685fee23be2469155

```
var people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Id = 1 },
    new Person { Id = 2 },
};

var hits = new List<IHit<Person>>
{
    new Mock<IHit<Person>>().Object
};

var mockSearchResponse = new Mock<ISearchResponse<Person>>();
mockSearchResponse.Setup(x => x.Documents).Returns(people);
mockSearchResponse.Setup(x => x.Hits).Returns(hits);

var mockElasticClient = new Mock<IElasticClient>();

mockElasticClient.Setup(x => x
    .Search(It.IsAny<Func<SearchDescriptor<Person>, ISearchRequest>>()))
.Returns(mockSearchResponse.Object);
```